# Tensorflow, large image inference - not enough memory

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, ram

I have trained a super-resolution model. The inference works:

```
def inference(self, filename):
    img_in = misc.imread(filename) / 255.0
    res = self.sess.run(self.out, feed_dict={ self.x: [img_in], self.is_training: False, self.lr_input: 0.0 })[0] * 255.0
    image = misc.toimage(res, cmin=0, cmax=255)
    fn_res = filename.replace(".png", "_result.png").replace(".jpg", "_result.jpg")
    misc.imsave(fn_res, image)
```

But when the image is larger than 600x600px, it says:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm using 16GB RAM and 16GB swapfile, inferencing using CPU. But the swapfile set up in Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't help despite it being enough.

I know I can workaround this by splitting image into pieces and processing them in order. But in the output there are visible marks of splitting.

Why doesn't it work? Is there any way I can implement memory swapfile using Python or Tensorflow? Are there any other workarounds?

Comment: Why not installing TF with GPU support? I guess Ubuntu also have GPU-support variant.

Comment: My GPU has 12GB of graphics RAM, but my motherboard has 16GB. That's why

Comment: as far as i know the total RAM on GPU and CPU is not related at all. I mean, no matter which is higher to each other. As long as the GPU memory can support your big task, then it should give a go.

Comment: If I inference using CPU, Tensorflow uses my RAM. If I inference using GPU, Tensorflow uses GPU memory.

Comment: how did you know that when you inference with GPU, it wont use RAM? I mean, when im inferencing, it still uses my RAM because my GPU memory is not big enough.

Comment: I didn't know that it uses both because I didn't look into the system monitor. My previous comment is nothing more than my logical assumption. Anyway, my problem is already solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by splitting the image into pieces, processing them one by one and combining them. To avoid visible "split lines" in the output image, I repeat the process described above with different piece sizes and calculate the mean.

I ended up with this:

```
def inference(self, filename, self_ensemble=False):
    img_q = Image.open(filename)

    scale = 4

    if img_q.width > 400:
        total = np.zeros((img_q.height * scale, img_q.width * scale, 3))
        #repeat 7 times with different piece size
        for x in range(7):
            total += self.inference_inter(filename, scale, 32 * (x + 8), ensemble=self_ensemble)

        total = total / 7.0

        image = misc.toimage(total, cmin=0, cmax=255)
        fn_res = filename.replace(".png", "_result.png").replace(".jpg", "_result.jpg")
        misc.imsave(fn_res, image)
    else:
        img_in = misc.imread(filename) / 255.0
        res = self.sess.run(self.out, feed_dict={ self.x: [img_in], self.is_training: False, self.lr_input: 0.0 })[0] * 255.0
        image = misc.toimage(res, cmin=0, cmax=255)
        fn_res = filename.replace(".png", "_result.png").replace(".jpg", "_result.jpg")
        misc.imsave(fn_res, image)


def inference_inter(self, filename, scale, pat_size, ensemble=True):
    img_in = misc.imread(filename) / 255.0
    img_q = Image.open(filename)

    res = np.zeros((img_q.height * scale, img_q.width * scale, 3))

    for qx in range(0, img_q.width, pat_size):
        for qy in range(0, img_q.height, pat_size):
            res[(qy * scale):((qy + pat_size) * scale)][(qx * scale):((qx + pat_size) * scale)] = self.sess.run(self.out, feed_dict={ self.x: [img_in[qy:(qy + pat_size)][qx:(qx + pat_size)]], self.is_training: False, self.lr_input: 0.0 })[0] * 255.0

    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

This paper addresses your problem and explains, why it exists:

https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3132847.3132872

If you can't access it, here are some cites / a summary:

### There are 2 problems: padding and normalization.

### Padding:

When doing a convolution, the net needs to fill in missing pixel values on the border of the image. That is because the kernel of the first couple of border-pixel lay outside of the provided image.

### Normalization:

> In convolution network, batch normalization technique is applied to speed up the convergence and reduce the internal covariate shift.
>
> Now, suppose we split the image into two sub-images. We get two small batches. If they go through the CNN independently, we will obtain two normalization results which only apply sub-images’ local means and variances in the computations. Therefore, even if we merge those pieces back to one image, we will end up with a result that is visually different from the one generated for the whole image.

---

### They propose the following solutions:

### Padding:

> For internal border, we use a novel padding technique, dictionary padding.

This means they use the corresponding pixel values of the neighbouring sub-image.

> For external border, we use circular paddings...

This means you pad on the right with the pixels from the left of the image, as if you had concatenated the image on the right (and vice versa). (Same with top-bottom)

### Normalization:

This is a bit more complex. In the end, they normalize the sub-images share the normalization values (mean and variance) between the images and combine them together.

---

The padding may be easy to implement, but I don't know how to do the normalization part with tensorflow. If someone figure it out and sends some code of that I would be very grateful.

Comment: That paper looks very promising but without code it is sort of frustrating.